# How do I split a really long, memory intensive loop into smaller chunks

Tags: php, loops, http-headers

I have quite a long, memory intensive loop. I can't run it in one go because my server places a time limit for execution and or I run out of memory.

I want to split up this loop into smaller chunks.

I had an idea to split the loop into smaller chunks and then set a location header to reload the script with new starting conditions.

MY OLD SCRIPT (Pseudocode. I'm aware of the shortcomings below)

```
for($i=0;$i<1000;$i++)
{
  //FUNCTION
}
```

MY NEW SCRIPT

```
$start=$_GET['start'];
$end=$start+10;

for($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++;)
{
   //FUNCTION
}

header("Location:script.php?start=$end");
```

However, my new script runs successfully for a few iterations and then I get a server error "Too many redirects"

Is there a way around this? Can someone suggest a better strategy?

I'm on a shared server so I can't increase memory allocation or script execution time.

I'd like a PHP solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what your loops does.  Can you post more code?

Comment: PHP really sucks at garbage collection. there are a lot of suggestions out there and improvements to the base code recently (including a new GC library), but I've tinkered with them all and in some cases, PHP just won't clear the memory, no matter how many unsets or sleeps you do. Try the various answers given, but be aware that if none work, you may be hitting your head against the wall.

Comment: does your loop include sql queries?

Answer (score 2):

"Too many redirects" is a browser error, so a PHP solution would be to use cURL or standard streams to load the initial page and let it follow all redirects. You would have to run this from a machine without time-out limitations though (e.g. using CLI)

Another thing to consider is to use AJAX. A piece of JavaScript on your page will run your script, gather the output from your script and determine whether to stop (end of computation) or continue (start from X). This way you can create a nifty progress meter too ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into [forking child processes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) to do the work. These child processes can do the work in smaller chunks in their own memory space, while the parent process fires off multiple children. This is commonly handled by Gearman, but can be done without.

Take a look at [Forking PHP](http://dealnews.com/developers) on Dealnews' Developers site. It has a library and some sample code to help manage code that needs to spawn child processes.

Answer (score 0):

First off, without knowing what your doing inside the loop, it's hard to tell you the best approach to actually solving your issue. However, if you want to execute something that takes a really long time, my suggestion would be to set up a cron job and let it nail out little portions at a time. The script would log where it stops and the next time it starts up, it could read the log for where to start.

---

Edit: If you are dead set against cron, and you aren't too concerned about user experience, you could do this:

Let the page load similar to the cron job above. Except after so many seconds or iterations, stop the script. Display a refresh meta tag or javascript refresh. Do this until the task is done.

Comment: Thanks Tom,the script inside the loop is not an issue. It could be anything at all. The important thing is that it is time and memory intensive by nature, not poor design. A cron job might be overkill for this application. The script is time and memory intensive by my server configuration standards only. It should only take 2 or 3 minutes to run.  I could simply change the header to a link for the next block and just click it 40 times, but I want to be able to run it conveniently and automatically.

Comment: The meta refresh / javascript refresh would happen automatically. If this isn't want you want, look into forking as Clay Hinson has stated.

Answer (score 0):

Generally if I have to iterate over something many many times and it has a decent amount of data, I use a "lazy load" type application like:

```
for($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++;)
{
   $data_holder[] = "adding my big data chunks!";
   if($i % 5 == 1){   
    //function to process data
    process_data($data_holder); // process that data like a boss!
    unset($data_holder); // This frees up the memory
   }
}

 // Now pick up the stragglers of whatever is left in the data chunk
 if(count($data_holder) > 0){
    process_data($data_holder);
 }
```

That way you can continue to iterate through your data, but you don't stuff up your memory. You can work in chunks, then unset the data, work in chunks, unset data, etc.. to help prevent memory. As far as execution time, that depends on how much you have to do / how efficient your script is written.

The basic premise -- "Process your data in smaller chunks to avoid memory issues. Keep your design simple to keep it fast."

Comment: Cheers, this definitely helps solve the memory problem. But in some cases I will still have an issue with the script execution time limit.

Comment: @Matt, Try plugging `set_time_limit(0);` into the modulus if statement. You may not be able to change the execution time, but you may be able to trick it into thinking the execution time has started over. Upvotes for being helpful are appreciated, selecting as answer if it is the most applicable / helpful is more appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about you put a conditional inside your loop to sleep every 100 iterations?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
    if ($i % 100 == 0)
        sleep(1800) //Sleep for half an hour
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the limitations you have, I think the approach you are using could work.  It may be that your browser is trying to be smart and not let you redirect back the page you were just on. It might be trying to prevent an endless loop.

You could try

- Redirecting back and forth between two scripts that are identical (or aliases).
- A different browser.
- Having your script output an HTML page with a refresh tag, e.g.

  `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://example.com/script.php?start=xxx">`

Comment: Hey, that works. I never knew you could set the url for the refresh tag. It's not as fluid as I want, but it gets the job done.

Comment: I'd rather say "Fix the car." than "But it can still go 55 if I push it off a cliff!"

Comment: @Blake, I agree with you, but see "with the limitations you have" and "but it gets the job done."

Comment: @bmb, I also believe there is also a direction correlation of perceived limitations to amount of effort willing to put forth.